# PYTHON ejecutar script cada cierto tiempo y al mismo tiempo ejecutar lo que queda del scrip

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

¿Cómo están?.

Tenía dos dudas con Python sobre ejecutar un script basado en el tiempo.
Por ejemplo, el script se ejecuta todos los días a una hora determinada (obviamente, puedo crear un Def y luego un time.sleep()) calculando la hora.

Pero ahora vienen las dudas:
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que este script mientras está en "suspensión" siga ejecutando el resto del código?
¿Cómo puedo calcular el tiempo que tarda un script en ejecutarse? (Se me ocurre en usar un datetime al principio y otra al final, restándolos) ¿hay otra forma?

pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda

```
import time

def ejecutaScript():
    print ('aca va el codigo numero 1')
    time.sleep(100)

while True:
    ejecutaScript()

for i in range(10):
    print('aca seguria un segundo codigo")
```

Para entender, el código uno que se ejecutará cada (100 segundos). pero mientras espero estos 100 segundos me gustaría continuar ejecutando el resto del código (me refiero al código número dos).
Y la segunda pregunta. Me gustaría saber cuanto demora todo el código en correr.

Saludos y que tengan un excelente día

Comment: Si estás en Unix lo más sencillo será que implementes dos scripts separados y uses cron para especificar con qué intervalo lanzar cada uno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución a tu problema es usar *threads*.

**¿Qué es un thread?**

Un thread es una función que se ejecuta en paralelo con otras funciones. Se construye igual que cualquier otra función.

Luego de escribir tu función (mira el ejemplo), creas un thread con

```
hilo = threading.Thread(target=ejecucion_horaria, args=(10,))
hilo.start()
```

Observaciones:

1. `args` es una lista de argumentos que se pasara a la funcion al comenzar. Si la función recibe sólo un argumento, tienes que colocar una coma al final, para que sea una lista. Si no pones la coma, Python la interpretara como una expresión numérica.
2. Debes usar el **nombre** de la función (sin parentesis). Si pones parentesis estarás pasando el valor de la función, que no es lo mismo.
3. La llamada te devuelve un objeto thread, con el cual controlas la ejecución. Luego de recibir el objeto `hilo`, lo haces partir llamando al método `start()`.

La función que escribas es como cualquier otra. Te recomiendo escribirla y probarla sola, y luego convertirla en un thread.

El thread puede ejecutar indefinidamente, o terminar. Queda a tu criterio y necesidad.

Los threads comparten las variables globales entre si y con el código principal, igual que cualquier otra función. Puedes usar esto para compartir datos.

**Ejemplo**

Vamos a hacer un thread que ejecute algo simple (un print() cada tantos segundos) mientras que el código principal hace lo suyo (otro print() cada tantos segundos).

En este ejemplo, el número de impresiones está limitado. Cuando el thread imprime la cantidad programada, la función sale y el thread se termina solo.

```
import time
import threading

def ejecucion_horaria(segundos):
    """
    Este es un thread con parametros.
    
    @param segundos: Ejecuta un print cada tantos segundos. 
    """
    print("Thread ejecuta cada %d" % segundos)
    for i in range(10):
        print("Ejecucion horaria, pasada %d" % i)
        time.sleep(segundos)

# Aqui creamos el thread.
# El primer argumento es el nombre de la funcion que contiene el codigo.
# El segundo argumento es una lista de argumentos para esa funcion .
# Ojo con la coma al final!

hilo = threading.Thread(target=ejecucion_horaria, args=(10,))
hilo.start()   # Iniciamos la ejecución del thread,

# La ejecución sigue de inmediato aqui, mientras el thread 
# ejecuta en paralelo. 
for i in range(100):
    print("Ejecución principal, pasada %d" % i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Este ejemplo produce:

```
Thread ejecuta cada 10
Ejecución principal, pasada 0
Ejecucion horaria, pasada 0
Ejecución principal, pasada 1
Ejecución principal, pasada 2
Ejecución principal, pasada 3
Ejecución principal, pasada 4
Ejecución principal, pasada 5
Ejecución principal, pasada 6
Ejecución principal, pasada 7
Ejecución principal, pasada 8
Ejecución principal, pasada 9
Ejecucion horaria, pasada 1
Ejecución principal, pasada 10
Ejecución principal, pasada 11
Ejecución principal, pasada 12
Ejecución principal, pasada 13
Ejecución principal, pasada 14
Ejecución principal, pasada 15
Ejecución principal, pasada 16
Ejecución principal, pasada 17
Ejecución principal, pasada 18
Ejecución principal, pasada 19
Ejecucion horaria, pasada 2
Ejecución principal, pasada 20
Ejecución principal, pasada 21
... etc ...
```

Comment: Muy Bueno Candid Moe ... y muy bien explicado... excelente aporte en la comunidad :D

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago para saber cuanto se demora en ejecutar es esto

```
from datetime import datetime
instanteInicial = datetime.now()
instanteFinal = datetime.now()
tiempo = instanteFinal - instanteInicial # Devuelve un objeto 
segundos = tiempo.seconds
```

Y para que se ejecute lo demás en vez de poner

> time.sleep(100)

ocupar algo como

```
if segundos%100==0:
```

ojala te funcione